# Finding the total permutations of the cards in the hand.

Tags: probability

There are $36$ unique cards containing $9$ ranks ($1$-$9$) of $4$ suits (diamonds, hearts, clubs, and spades). A hand is a collection of $9$ cards. The hand must contain all $4$ of the $1$s (one from each suit). Find the total permutations of the hand from the cards that are left to pick and the four $1$'s.

So my guess is there are already $4$ cards of $1$s in the hand so the permutation is: $$(4!)\cdot(32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29\cdot 28)$$ Is this correct?

Comment: The $32*31*30*29*28$ part is ok but the $4$! is wrong.  It should be $9$!/$5$! which is $9*8*7*6$ so your answer is $126$ times too low.  The reason for this is because the way you are doing it you are "confining" the position of the four $1$s to say the first $4$ positions and then permuting those only in those spots and doing the same for the last $5$ cards, only permuting them in those last $5$ spots but you should be allowed (once you get all $9$ cards) to permute all of them into any of the $9$ positions so that is the only place where you went wrong so nice try but "no cigar".

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really clear.  For any $9$ card hand you pick/get, there are $9$! permutations of it.  A permutation would be just a reordering of the same $9$ cards in this example.  A hand is defined as $9$ cards here so if you mean how many permutations of a complete $9$ card hand, then again it is $9$!.

If you mean how many permutations are there of a $9$ card hand that must contain the four $1$s but also counting the # of ways to complete the hand, then it would be $32 \choose 5$ ways to complete the hand and $9$! ways to permute the hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad to help.  Since you find my answer useful/helpful, can you please click on the up arrows by my answer and also the other person that answered and helped you too?  I like to get something for my effort.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nine unique cards have $9!$ permutations.

There are ${4\choose 4}{36-4\choose 9-4}$ ways to choose all four `1` and five other cards from the deck of thirty six.

So if you want to count the distinct ways to select *and* arrange a hand of nine cards containing all four `1`, put it together.

Comment: Right, I get it now. Thank you!